# Grouping the results of a group query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following sample data:

```
{
    "name": "Bob",
    "mi": "K",
    "martialStatus": "M",
    "age": 30,
    "city": "Paris",
    "job": "Engineer"
}
{
    "name": "Chad",
    "mi": "M",
    "martialStatus": "W",
    "age": 31,
    "city": "Paris",
    "job": "Doctor"
}
{
    "name": "Mel",
    "mi": "A",
    "martialStatus": "D",
    "age": 31,
    "city": "London",
    "job": "Doctor"
}
{
    "name": "Frank",
    "mi": "F",
    "martialStatus": "S",
    "age": 30,
    "city": "London",
    "job": "Engineer"
}
```

I am trying to write a mongo query that would return results in the following format:
    "peopleCount": 4,
    "jobsList": {
        "job": "Doctor",
        "ageList": [
            {
                "age": 31,
                "cityList": [ 
                    {
                        "city": "London",
                        "people": [
                            {
                                "name": "Mel",
                                "martialStatus": "D"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "city": "Paris",
                        "people": [
                            {
                                "name": "Chad",
                                "martialStatus": "W"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                   {
                        "city": "Berlin",
                            ...
                            ...
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

To try on the first two level (jobsList and ageList), I am trying the below

```
db.colName.aggregate([
    { 
        $group: { 
            _id: { job: "$job" },
            jobsList: {
                $push: {
                    age: "$age",
                    city: "$city",
                    name: "$name",
                    martialStatus: "$martialStatus"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { age: "$age" }, 
            ageList: {
                $push: {
                    city: "$city", 
                    name: "$name", 
                    martialStatus: "$martialStatus"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

The above however does not work although the first group/push part works... Any hints on how to get that output format/groupping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
db.colName.aggregate([
{
    $group: {
        _id: { job: "$job", age: "$age", city: "$city" },
        people: { $push: { name: "$name", martialStatus: "$martialStatus" } }
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: { job: "$_id.job", age: "$_id.age" },
        peopleCount: { $sum: { $size: "$people" } },
        cityList: { $push: { city: "$_id.city", people: "$people" } },
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: { job: "$_id.job" },
        peopleCount: { $sum: "$peopleCount" },
        agesList: { $push: { age: "$_id.age", cityList: "$cityList" } }
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        peopleCount: { $sum: "$peopleCount" },
        jobsList: { $push: { job: "$_id.job", agesList: "$agesList" } }
    }
},
{
    $project: { _id: 0, peopleCount: 1, jobsList: 1 }
}
]);
```

on the provided by you collection gives me the result

```
{
  "peopleCount" : 4,
  "jobsList" : 
  [ 
    { 
      "job" : "Engineer", 
      "agesList" : 
        [ 
          { 
            "age" : 30, 
            "cityList" : 
              [ 
                { 
                  "city" : "London", 
                  "people" : 
                    [ 
                      { "name" : "Frank", "martialStatus" : "S" } 
                    ] 
                }, 
                { 
                  "city" : "Paris", 
                  "people" : 
                    [ 
                      { "name" : "Bob", "martialStatus" : "M" } 
                    ] 
                } 
              ] 
          } 
        ]
    },
    { 
      "job" : "Doctor", 
      "agesList" : 
        [ 
          { 
            "age" : 31, 
            "cityList" : 
              [ 
                { 
                  "city" : "London", 
                  "people" : 
                    [ 
                      { "name" : "Mel", "martialStatus" : "D" } 
                    ] 
                }, 
                { 
                  "city" : "Paris", 
                  "people" : 
                    [ 
                      { "name" : "Chad", "martialStatus" : "W" } 
                    ] 
                } 
              ] 
          } 
        ] 
    } 
  ] 
}
```

that seems to be correct. Thought, I am not sure it's the best solution. I am new to aggregation-framework.

Comment: This worked as expected. Thank you and good way to start aggregation-framework :).

Comment: Would it be possible to show case how to add another argument at the top before joblist: "peopleCount": 4

Comment: Is it possible in your case that one person lives in multiple cities or has multiple jobs, thus in your collection there will be several documents corresponding to one person?

Comment: An answer depends on whether you want 
`{ "name": "Bob", "mi": "K", "martialStatus": "M", "age": 30, "city": "Paris", "job": "Engineer" }` and 
`{ "name": "Bob", "mi": "K", "martialStatus": "M", "age": 30, "city": "Lyon", "job": "Software developer" }` to add 1 or 2 to `peopleCount`. In other words, is there a unique identifier of a person, or `personCount` should be just the size of all documents in you collection?

Comment: It should be the count of documents, just unsure where to integrate it in your proposed query to show it on top...

Comment: I updated an answer, let me know if it works for you. And include this new request to your question.

Comment: pls help if you can for related questions in mongoDB - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61067856/calculate-dwell-time-between-2-statuses-of-a-field